# How can i make a ragdoll body that splits up?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, split, 2d

How can I make a 3D bodypart split from a 3D body. [2D Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmTdee0q74k)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use multiple individual parts to make a complete working player e.g Arms, hands , Legs, Foot ,in the game, and later split them by adding rigid Body and using RigidBody.addforce in direction opposite of the main body during game-play.

One way would be to instantiate the parts to the position of the player,Destroy the Player object,  and then use AddForce to 'throw' the instantiated parts.